# How do I set up multiple Firebase projects with the same bundle ID on Android?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm working on an Android app that uses Firebase for a few different functions. I'm currently trying to expand from a single Firebase project to 3 to represent development, staging, and production environments.

All of my projects need to use the same bundle ID because of a restriction by another tool I'm using (RevenueCat). What I'm noticing with this setup is that, even when using different `google-services.json` files, I'm always pointing to my original, production Firebase project.

I've searched around and seen some things about needing to add SHA-1 values on Android to differentiate the apps. I've tried adding the SHA-1 from the app signing key certificate in the Google Play Console to the production project and the SHA-1 from the `./gradlew signingReport` output to the staging project. Still no dice, unfortunately.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of setup or any other ideas to try? Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you explain more why you need to use exact same bundle ID for debug/uat/prod, I have no experience with RevenueCat but what's the restrictions.

Comment: Yeah of course. RevenueCat mainly acts as an abstraction layer between native payments on Android/iOS and the app code.


However, the way your in-app purchases are set up is all on the native stores, and the stores require you to specify your single bundle ID for your app (as far as I'm aware). So for example, I can't specify my bundle ID on the Google Play Console as `com.example.app` / `com.example.app.dev` / `com.example.staging`.

Comment: Why don't you just make three apps in RevenueCat as well? So there's an app in Firebase + RevenueCat for each environment?

Comment: Unfortunately the source of truth is the App Store/Google Play Store. So I'm pretty sure that would involve creating 3 separate apps in each of those, and I feel like there's got to be a better solution than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it turns out I just needed to clear out the `app/build` folder. Apparently the Firebase configs get "cached" in some way between builds, so clearing it forces it to use the new configuration.

I've just added it as a step in the build process. After this small change, everything is working as expected.

Comment: 2 years later, and I'm trying to accomplish the same thing you were. Thank you for asking and answering your own question. Can you clarify 2 things?

1. Did you use the SHA-1 technique at all for your final solution?
2. Did clearing `app/build` on build continue to work to have the right Firebase target?

Thank you so much, if you see this.

Comment: @RossLlewallyn this is where I'm at too.  Firebase throws an error for duplicate  SHA-1 fingerprint.  Were you able to rerun this aspect?

Answer (score 1):

Having several different apps inside one project with the same bundleId/packageName is impossible. You have the possibility to use one `google-services.json` for several apps, though - you just need to add several apps to your project. The packageName/bundleId of those apps should be different, though.

It is very usual for your case - splitting the app into several flavors to have an appId suffix. For example `com.example.app.prod`, `com.example.app.stage`, `com.example.app.dev` - the suffix can be configure in the `gradle.build` for each flavor. The issue is that you will have to have different apps inside the firebase project or different projects for each flavor - depending on your needs. For example, when the apps are part of the same project, they will share auth and database storage but will have separate crashlitycs, etc. The different projects will have everything different.

SHA-1 is a bit different thing - it is meant to limit/enable/disable the usage of the APIs based on the signing certificate. There may be several SHA-1 for the same package name. Moreover, SHA-1 only works for Android apps.

**What you can do is to create several projects - one for each flavor and register the app under the same package name inside each one - you are able to do that! Each flavor will have to have its own `google-services.json` file in the appropriate folder.**

It works really well with the different package names.

I have never tried this approach with the same packageName, and I don't know the possible drawbacks, so I assume you may face some issues. Or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   

I actually previously followed the structure you laid out: different IDs per flavor (`com.example.app.prod`, `com.example.app.stage`, `com.example.app.dev`) along with separate Firebase projects for each. I had a system to use the correct `google-services.json` at build-time.  

The issue is really just adapting this to a single app ID. My Android app is always pointing to the same Firebase project now no matter which `google-services.json` I use.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, a simple configuration using google-services.json will be enough for having different Firebase environments in your App. But as we saw, things can get complex very quickly, and depending on the requirements custom ways for configuration and initialization of the Firebase services can be needed. I this article I tried to summarize the different approaches for achieving this goal and share my personal experience. I hope that it was helpful to you and that you enjoyed it.